# Get User Activity from User ID - Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to a user's current activity (Playing Game, Online, Offline) from the user ID. I have all intents enabled. Here's my code which doesn't work:

```
member1 = bot.get_user(5242612345674376)
print(member1.activity)
```

Output:

```
Initating BOT
'Bot Connected!'
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Projects\newtest.py", line 33, in on_ready
    print(member1.activity)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'activity'
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: `52426-USERID-74376` is not a valid Python identifer (variable name), but you are using it as if it were a variable. So I'm guessing you meant to enclose it in quotation marks so it's treated as a string literal. If quoting doesn't fix it, then please edit your post to include [a minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) excerpt of your code plus the exact output or error message.

Comment: bot.get_channel() and these take integers, I wrote -USERID- in between to hide the actual user id and show it more clearly.

Comment: That's one reason you ought to post a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Added the output and fixed the input

Comment: The [User API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) doesn't seem to have any attribute like `activity`. But the [Member API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) does. So if you used `get_member` instead of `get_user`, ...

Comment: The client had no attribute like activity, the guild does. So I had to get the guild and the get the member like you had pointed out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have figured it out. Here is the code**

```
#Using it on on_message() or you can use GuildID or just guilds    
guild = bot.get_guild(message.guild.id)
#Member's UserID here  
member1 = guild.get_member(0123456789) 
print(member1.activities)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't get a user activity with [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#id8). so use [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#member):

```py
user = bot.get_user(5242612345674376) # get user

mutual_guild = user.mutual_guilds[0]  # get a mutual server

member = discord.utils.get(mutual_guild.members(), id=user.id) 
# get user as a member with first mutual guild and id number

print(member.activity)
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, can you mark my answer as the correct answer?